Stability on manifold with boundary
Let $(X,\partial X)$ a smooth Kahler manifold with boundary, i.e. the interior of $X$ is Kahler, Donaldson proved that:
Given a smooth vector bundle $E$ over $X$ such that $E$ is holomorphic over the interior, or equivalently a connection $\bar{\partial}_A$ on $E$ which defines holomorphic structure on the interior and bounded along $\partial X$. Then for any smooth metric $g$ on $E|_{\partial X}$, we can extend $g$ over $X$ uniquely (the extension also denoted by $g$) such that $g$ is HYM on interior of $X$, i.e. $i\Lambda F_g=0$.
Reference: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0393044092900442
In the algebraic geometry language, this theorem says that under the setting above any holomorphic vector bundle is automatically stable.
I wonder if this theorem also hold in singular case? More precisely, consider holomorphic vector bundle $E,\bar{\partial}_A$ over $X,\partial X$, if we allow the connection $\bar{\partial}_A$ on $E$ have singularity along $\partial X$, then for given metric $g$ of $E$ over $\partial X$, can we extend $g$ to the whole $X$ such that, $i\Lambda F_g=0$?
